# Model separate Person types as separate tables at beginning of application's lifetime?

Tags: database-design

If I have a couple of distinct types of Person that will always have a set of disjoint fields, should I go ahead and model them with two different tables?

For example, say I'm setting up a system that connects Worker with Hiring Manager, where both are expected to be individual humans. These two different types of Person will never share members.

At the application layer, I don't expect either of these two types of people to log in, initially, but at some point in the application's life, they will have emails and passwords and so on.

What's the best approach at the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

My gut feeling (which seems to be borne out somewhat by [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/4152/23383)) is that you should go ahead and do different tables, since you can always migrate later to a schema where these different Persons all have the same kind of Account associated 1:1 (as suggested in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/81640/23383)).

Comment: This question is somewhat unanswerable without additional information.  Sure, it can be done with two tables.  It can also be done with one.  What is the objective?  Are you concerned that the table will be too large at some point and therefore perform badly?

Comment: BTW, another option would be to have 3 tables.  One for the person with their types (one table only)  then each type could have a joined table which contained the other non-consistent columns.  That would probably make the most sense and be the most normalized if that is in fact your goal.

Comment: @ShooterMcGavin That was a big reason why I put "at the beginning of application lifetime". I think requirements might change down the road, so I wanted to see what the best answer was as far as YAGNI and extensibility.

Comment: Beginning of application lifetime doesn't really provide much more information. Also, you would never want to plan on changing your database tables down the road. If possible it's best to allow for growth at the beginning. Its not always possible but it should still be the goal. That being said, you wish to allow for growth and additional requirements, that's a good objective. In that case, go for the fully normalized approach with 1 table for the person. 1 table for each type that has different columns. Then link back using the person id.